# Android AppWidget on orientation changed

Tags: android, android-asynctask, android-widget, screen-orientation

I understand my question sounds old and I did search a lot on SO but could not figure out how to solve it.

I created an App Widget with a Refresh button which allow user to load information from Internet. Whenever user click Refresh, the widget will execute an Asynctask to download information.

```
@Override
public void onUpdate(Context context, AppWidgetManager appWidgetManager, int[] appWidgetIds) {

    for (int appWidgetId: appWidgetIds) {
           //update app widget
    }
}

@Override
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {

    if (REFRESH_LIST.equals(intent.getAction())) {
          //Execute AsyncTask to download information from Internet and update widget listview
    }
}
```

The widget is working perfectly except only when user click Refresh and rotate the screen while the AsyncTask is still running on background, then the whole widget settings and data of that widget instance are lost.

So anyone ever experienced same problem please cross me a finger. Thank you!!

Comment: After playing with this widget a while, I found that as long as the RemoteViews are not involved in the AsyncTask (I wanted to display a ProgressBar while downloading information) then the widget and AsyncTask should be running fine on orientation changed. 

Hope this could help anyone encountering same issues.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After playing with this widget a while, I found that as long as the RemoteViews are not involved in the AsyncTask (I wanted to display a ProgressBar while downloading information) then the widget and AsyncTask should be running fine on orientation changed. Hope this could help anyone encountering same issues.

Answer (score 0):

You do not need to use `AsynTask` there. 
Click on *Refresh* button at widget would send intent to your service. This service would care about updating information from Internet and when task will be done care about updating widget (again by intent). In this way, changing of orientation won't break your task at service.

**Assumption:**
I guess, you won't be able to handle orientation change by your current implementation. Because system system simple re-create new Widget during it. In this case `AsyncTask` task is still running and will be finished at old widget (which lefts in memory), but don't apply to new one.

Comment: Thanks for your respond. In fact, I did try to put the Internet information updating code inside onReceive() but end up with Exception

java.lang.RuntimeException: android.os.NetworkOnMainThreadException